# Params of button always empty even after clicking jsf

Tags: jsf, jsf-2.2

I am opening a modal which has form in it. I am trying to check if the button is clicked or not by `#{empty param['buttonid']}`. But it is always shows empty even when clicked.

```
<div class="modal fade" jsf:id="dataReset">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
             <form jsf:id="reset-data-form" class="form-horizontal">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">                  
                        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="inputEmail" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Email</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-9">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" 
                                       jsf:id="inputEmail" jsf:value="#{dataResetFacade.dataResetEmail}"                          
                                       name="inputEmail" />
                                <h:message for="inputEmail" p:class="error-msg"/>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button class="btn btn-default"
                            data-dismiss="modal">#{msg['general.button.cancel']}</button>
                        <button class="btn btn-primary" jsf:id="reset-data-button" 
                            jsf:action="#{dataResetFacade.resetdata}">submit
                            <f:ajax execute="@form" render="@form aaa bbb messages" onevent="close"/>
                        </button>
                         <h:outputText id="aaa" value="#{not empty param['reset-data-button']}"/>
                         <h:outputText id="bbb" value="#{empty param['reset-data-button']}"/>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Am I doing some thing wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You did not specify the right request parameter name there. The request parameter name is basically the JSF component's client ID. The client ID of a JSF input and button component is represented by the HTML element's `name` attribute. You can find it out by just looking at the JSF-generated HTML output via rightclick, *View Source* in webbrowser.

Given the current view, that'll look like as below:

```
<button name="reset-data-form:reset-data-button" ... />
```

Alter parameter names accordingly:

```
<h:outputText id="aaa" value="#{not empty param['reset-data-form:reset-data-button']}" />
<h:outputText id="bbb" value="#{empty param['reset-data-form:reset-data-button']}" />
```

Alternatively, just bind the JSF [`UIComponent`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/faces/component/UIComponent.html) instance to an unique variable name in Facelet scope using `binding` attribute and then let JSF evaluate the [`UIComponent#getClientId()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/faces/component/UIComponent.html#getClientId()).

```
<button jsf:binding="#{resetButton}" ... />
...
<h:outputText id="aaa" value="#{not empty param[resetButton.clientId]}" />
<h:outputText id="bbb" value="#{empty param[resetButton.clientId]}" />
```

Note: do **not** bind it to a bean property. The above code is as-is.

#### See also:

- [How does the 'binding' attribute work in JSF? When and how should it be used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14911158/how-does-the-binding-attribute-work-in-jsf-when-and-how-should-it-be-used)